# How much higher is the legendary drop rate in the Torment difficulties?

Tags: diablo-iii

The ingame explanation of the different difficulty levels states that the Torment difficulties increase the drop rate of legendaries. But they don't state exactly how large this increase is.

I've farmed a bit on Normal difficulty and found some nice stuff, but I'm also roughly able to farm at Torment I difficulty. I'm wondering if the large decrease in speed compared to Normal is worth it for me, but to judge that I need to know a bit better how large the increase in legendary drop rate is.

Comment: When you say Normal, I assume you don't mean the lowest setting, because that would be crazy if you can handle Torment I

Comment: @Ramhound I mean Normal as the drop rates don't change until torment. I just did a few quick runs to gather some easy upgrades for my old character.

Comment: The exact change isn't known or hasn't been published by Blizzard.  Why are you running `Normal` instead of at least `Master`

Comment: When running from Areat Crater 2 to Asmodan (not kiling him) (~10/12min run) in T1 I loot about 1,5 to 2 leg/hour. Sometime I get lucky and loot 3 or 4 leg on one run (has happend twice) but then nothing for a while.

Comment: having done only torment since 2.0, I have to say the leg/hour is a drastic decrease when compared to 1.8 and max paragon MF

Answer (score 4):

From the [diablo forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11914131918?page=2), the legendaries drop rate is not disclosed as of now.

> Grimiku said:
>   Increasing the difficulty will increase the amount of damage that monsters do, give them extra health, and reward you with more gold and experience. Torment difficulties I - VI, however, also give you an better chance to find a Legendary item, and that chance scales up with difficulty. Here's the breakdown for most of the difficulty changes that's in our game guide. Remember, monsters scale with your character, so you'll normally be fighting monsters your level, or the party leader's level in a multiplayer game.
>
> Normal: +0% Health, +0% Damage, +0% Gold Find, +0% Experience
>
> Hard: +200% Health, +130% Damage, +75% Gold Find, +75% Experience
>
> Expert: +320% Health, +189% Damage, +100% Gold Find, +100% Experience
>
> Master: +512% Health, +273% Damage, +200% Gold Find, +200% Experience
>
> Torment I: +819% Health, +396% Damage, +300% Gold Find, +300% Experience
>
> Torment II: +1311% Health, +575% Damage, +400% Gold Find, +400% Experience
>
> Torment III: +2097% Health, +833% Damage, +550% Gold Find, +550% Experience
>
> Torment IV: +3355% Health, +1208% Damage, +800% Gold Find, +800% Experience
>
> Torment V: +5369% Health, +1752% Damage, +1150% Gold Find, +1150% Experience
>
> Torment VI: +8590% Health, +2540% Damage, +1600% Gold Find, +1600% Experience

Reading the whole thread of the forums, the difference of drop rate seems low enough to not warrant that a fast run would get you less legendaries than a slower at a higher difficulties. If you make a run at Normal a lot faster than at Torment 1, stay at normal. You might wanna try Master or Expert since the differences shouldn't be drastic if you can run T1.

If it only takes you 10-15 more mins at T1, go with T1. Only with tries out will you know which setting will net you more legendaries. For my part, I'll be lowering to T1 since T2 is a tad too slow for my taste even if I got 4 legendaries in about 4-5hrs of play.

Comment: Note that there are certain legendaries that only drop in Torment I - VI.  Also, item quality is unaffected by difficulty (e.g. a level 60 Nailbiter found in Normal has the exact same potential as a level 60 Nailbiter found in Torment VI).  Source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12091349617?page=5#89

Answer (score 4):

Legendary drop rate increases by 15% for every level of Torment (no change on Hard/Expert/Master) multiplicatively, and is further doubled while in Nephalem Rifts ([source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12471197317?page=12#236)).

So the whole table looks like:

```
                                                              [   speculative   ]
           Norm Hard Expt Mstr  T1   T2   T3   T4   T5   T6    T7   T8   T9   TX
Overworld  100% 100% 100% 100% 115% 132% 152% 175% 201% 231%  266% 306% 352% 405% 
Rift       200% 200% 200% 200% 230% 265% 304% 350% 402% 463%  532% 612% 704% 809%
```

Baseline drop rate is not known, though.